# How to disable VVDocumenter?

Tags: ios, xcode

I'm using VVDocumenter to makeup my codes.But it will replace `///` automatically.I want to disable this for just a little while.How to disable?Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [documentation](https://github.com/onevcat/VVDocumenter-Xcode):

> If you want to use other text beside of /// to trigger the document
>   insertion, you can find a setting panel by clicking VVDocument in the
>   Window menu of Xcode. You can also find some other useful options
>   there, including setting using spaces instead of tab in the panel or
>   changing the format of generated documentation.